# Thunderbird 68 won't import old account from ~/.thunderbird folder

Tags: thunderbird, manjaro

I reinstalled my system from ubuntu 20.04 do manjaro. 
I saved ~/.thunderbird folder from the old system to an external drive. After, I copied the folder back to home and started Thunderbird it does not seem to see the profile. Although it can read some of the data, like the Address Book but no account settings, no folders, nothing else.

I found the help page
https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/moving-thunderbird-data-to-a-new-computer
and tried to do it but it doesn't help. Thunderbird found my old profile and it is visible in about:profiles and set as the default profile, so everything looks like thunderbird has read the profile settings but does not understand them

Comment: Did you check the file permissions for the profile folder?

Answer (score 1):

If that fails, in Thunderbird
Edit->Account Settings->Server Settings.
At the bottom of the "Server Settings" tab should be a "Local directory" entry.
Make sure the Local directory MyProfile/Mail/mail.comcast.net (or whatever your profile's appropriate Mail mail-server subfolder is named) matches the full path name of your Thunderbird profile as installed on your new computer. You might have changed it.

Comment: I didn't find any wrong path names where you said, but grepping the profile directory revealed there were some wrong pathnames elsewhere. My old .thunderbird directory was symlinked to my encrypted volume and it turns out some pathnames within the profile had been fully resolved into the absolute paths so `/crypt/.thunderbird` instead of `/home/user/.thunderbird`. My new installation doesn't have a /crypt since my home directory is already encrypted, but by recreating that location with another symlink I have got it working.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a known issue, although I have not seen it myself. A colleague has been affected, though.

In brief: what happens if you launch Thunderbird with the `-p` option? It should list available profiles and let you choose one.

Longer potentially-helpful page:
https://thunderbirdtweaks.blogspot.com/2019/09/i-lost-my-profilemail-on-update-to.html